# Selenium IDE intermittent error - Element css=a.signout not found

Tags: selenium

trying Selenium IDE 2.2. I'm getting an intermittent error, I've tried slowing down the IDE but it still happens. I'm able to login on website using username and password but i'm not able to signout.

```
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>/portal/Welcome.do</td>
<td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>id=login</td>
<td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>name=username</td>
<td>sub3@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>name=password</td>
<td>sub3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>link=SIGN IN</td>
<td></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>css=a.signout</td>
<td></td>
     </tr>
```

Output:

```
[info] Executing: |open | /portal/Welcome.do | |
[info] Executing: |click | id=login | |
[info] Executing: |type | name=username | sub3@gmail.com |
[info] Executing: |type | name=password | sub3 |
[info] Executing: |click | link=SIGN IN | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | css=a.signout | |
**[error] Element css=a.signout not found**
```

Comment: We would need more information, a copy of the HTML of your site would be a start, even better, link to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, just maybe: What happens if you change

```
|click | link=SIGN IN | |
```

to

```
|clickAndWait | link=SIGN IN | |
```

The error could be that the logout link is not yet present when you try to click it, because page did not load completly.

But please consider this answer as plain guess, because I do not have much information to build on